# Как наследовать метод родительского класса для дочернего класса. Контекстное меню

Tags: python, ооп, tkinter

Подскажите пожалуйста, как наследовать метод self.context_menu из родительского класса Main , чтобы в дочернем классе New_win он тоже отображался.
Хочу сделать для дочернего окна вызов контекстного меню. По нажатию на правую кнопку мыши, контекстное меню не появляется.

Код ниже.

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk

class Main(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('1111111111111')
        self.geometry('300x300')
        self.context_menu()
        self.btn=ttk.Button(self,text='New',command=self.open)
        self.btn.pack()
        self.event_add('<<Paste>>','<Control-igrave>')
        self.event_add('<<Copy>>','<Control-ntilde>')
        self.event_add('<<Cut>>','<Control-division>')
        self.event_add('<<Undo>>','<Control-ydiaeresis>')
        self.event_add('<<SelectAll>>','<Control-ocircumflex>')
        self.e=Entry(self)
        self.e.pack()
    
    def context_menu(self):
        self.menu=Menu(self,tearoff=0)
        self.menu.add_command(label='Копировать', command=self.copy)
        self.menu.add_separator()
        self.menu.add_command(label='Вставить',command=self.paste)
        self.menu.add_separator()
        self.menu.add_command(label='Вырезать',command=self.cut)
        self.menu.add_separator()
        self.menu.add_command(label="Выбрать все",command=self.select_all)
        self.bind('<Button-3>',self.show_context)

    def show_context(self,e):
        self.menu.post(e.x_root,e.y_root)

    def copy(self):
        pass

    def paste(self):
        pass

    def cut(self):
        pass

    def select_all(self):
        pass


    def open(self):
        g=New_win(self)
        g.title('test')



class New_win(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent,*args,**kwargs)
        self.parent=parent
        self.geometry(self.parent.geometry())

        self.entry=ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.context_menu=self.parent.context_menu()
        self.context_menu()

        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=Main()
    app.mainloop()
```

Если класс New_win будет наследоваться от Main , то да , все будет работать. Но тогда получиться, что я буду класс New_win будет иметь все атрибуты класса Main, а мне необходимо наследовать только контекстное меню из класса Main.

Comment: Во дочернем окне контекстное меню должно вызывать методы основного окна или дочернего окна?

Comment: основного окна.

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось прощем чем я думал. Может еще буду варианты?

```
class New_win(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.entry=ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.bind('<Button-3>',self.parent.show_context)
```